# Add contact images to my recycler viewer contact numbers

Tags: java, android, image, android-contentresolver

What I would like to do is place a contact list in a recycler viewer. The contact list should have contact image , contact number and contact name. I've got the latter of the three sorted out but the thing is the images are not assigned to the contact names. Basically I would like each individual contact to have the image assigned to it from the contact list or Facebook. Can anybody try an see where I went wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
public class allContacts extends Fragment {
RecyclerView r;
ContactAdapter adapter;
List <contactInfo> contactLists = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_contacts, container, false);
    r =(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactView);
   loadContact contact = new loadContact();
    contact.execute();
    return view;
}


public class loadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<contactInfo>> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<contactInfo> contacts;
    contactInfo contact;
    String imnage;
    Cursor phonesCursor;
    Bitmap contactPhoto;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading Contacts", "Please Wait");
    }


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<contactInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");


        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                contact = new contactInfo();
                contact.setName(name);

                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    contact.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

                    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));


                    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contactId));
                    InputStream input = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(contentResolver, uri);
                    contactPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                }
                phoneCursor.close();


                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String emailId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                }
                contactLists.add(contact);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<contactInfo> contacts) {
        super.onPostExecute(contacts);
        pd.cancel();
        ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(contactLists, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        r.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        r.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }

}

public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactViewHolder> {
    private List<contactInfo> contactLists;
    private Context context;
    Cursor cursor;

    public ContactAdapter(List <contactInfo> contactLists , Context context) 
        this.contactLists =  contactLists;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contactviewer,null);
        ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view);
       return contactViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
        contactInfo contact = contactLists.get(position);
        holder.contactName.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.contactNumber.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
        loadContact l = new loadContact();
        holder.contactPic.setImageBitmap(l.contactPhoto);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactLists.size();
    }
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView contactPic;
    TextView contactName;
    TextView contactNumber;

    public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        contactPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView101);
        contactName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Text101);
        contactNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Text202);
    }
}



}

class contactInfo{
String phoneNumber;
String Name;
int image;


public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public contactInfo(){
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your onBindViewHolder method you are trying to setup same image again like this

```
loadContact l = new loadContact();
holder.contactPic.setImageBitmap(l.contactPhoto);
```

instead try setting

```
holder.contactPic.setImageBitmap(contact.getImage());
```